Sort EF Core results by distance from location using lat and lng
I have a table that contains lat and lng columns.
Now I want to sort this table's data based on a given location's lat and lng so that the closest location is displayed first and the rest are sorted based on the same principle.
IQueryable<Post> result = result.OrderBy(x => Haversine(x.BeginningLat ?? 0, lat ?? 0, x.BeginningLng ?? 0, lng?? 0));

private static double Haversine(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1, double lon2)
{
    const double r = 6378100; // meters

    var sdlat = Math.Sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2);
    var sdlon = Math.Sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2);

    var q = sdlat * sdlat + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * sdlon * sdlon;
    var d = 2 * r * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(q));

    return d;
}


What type is result? I would guess it is IQueryable<TSomething>. You try to use a function in C#, that should run on the server side in SQL? This won't work. You have to first fetch the data (e.g. .AsEnumerable() or .ToList()) and then apply your ordering.

If you are using Postgres or SQL Server have you considered using Spatial Data and STDistance()

@Charlieface Im using mysql

Looks like MySQL supports it also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.NetTopologySuite

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql supports Geospatial Distance.

@Charlieface my provider is pomelo  but I can't understand how to use MySQL gueries with EF Core. Could you help me make it work please

@SvyatoslavDanyliv could you tell me how I can use it please

It would be something along the lines of result.OrderBy(x => x.Location.Distance(myLocationVariable)) where Location is a spatial column. See the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial
